# Detect rotated vehicle images

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I want to rotated my vehicle images (90, 180, or 270 degree) to the right position.
I have used a hypothesis that is: rotate the image with 4 angle (0, 90, 180, 270) and give each one to an object detetion Neural Net, the angle that gives greatest car object confidence score will be the angle I have to use to rotate my image.
The problem is: Some images with 180 rotate give better score than the original, because the NN mistakenly detect the road with 2 wheels is the car. For example:
[The original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ov8EG.png)
[The rotated image but get better score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb0dI.png)

How can I can prevent that from happening?
My model: ssd_resnet_50_fpn_coco from [model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md)
Here is some other fail cases:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsFDh.jpg)  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkENP.jpg)  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65MkH.jpg)

Comment: What are you looking for in the images?

Comment: A simple hack might be to to check for the centroid of the bounding box. If it in the upper third of the image, then the image has been rotated 180 degrees--wheels can't be in the air! You can also test for the other rotations this way too. Interesting question & I'm sure there's better solutions!  Training another output layer could also help you solve the problem.

Comment: @MH304 I'm trying to find a way to detect whether my image is rotated or not by using the hypothesis I mention in the question

Comment: @SuhasC thanks for the hack, I'll check it out and let you know if it works

Comment: @SuhasC this is a poor hack because the picture could just be showing more road under the car

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution that is a bit tricky.
Firstly, I created a model (SSD for example) that will detect 4 classes which are the rotation angle of the image, i.e: class1 - 0 degree, class2 - 90 degree, etc.
The model, then, will find 2 label correctly out of 4: 0 and 180. If the label ran into 90 or 270 (which are sometimes recognized as one another), I will rotate them again with 90 degree and let the model predict what their label are between 0 and 180. After that, I will subtract the degree with 90 degree to get the right label.

Answer (score 2):

Search for wheels in the picture and determine if their centers are above or below the car box.